# Which document format is this?

Tags: java, c++, html, xml, pdf

I am trying to recollect the name of a document format.

- It's a plain text document, in an XML construct.
- The document of this format can be converted into html,pdf,doc and some other formats.
- The name is like : xxxdoc. I can't remember what the xxx is.

Will somebody have a hit?  thanks

Comment: [`docx`?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docx)

Comment: are you looking for fop-doc : [FOP] (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)

Comment: could it be XSL-FO, certainly fits your description



  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/xslfo_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)